# sparse to dense einsum in tensorflow

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

Is there a way to perform actions efficiently on sparse matrices when I have complicated operations? (actually I am not even sure how can my example be simplified to anything without slicing)

In the example I try to multiple inputs coming in a batch (b) with a complex kernel vector that is different for each example in the batch (as it was constructed by weights multiplied by another input). The inputs are dense, the kernel is sparse.

Example:

```
outputs = special_math_ops.einsum("bi,bnilo->bnlo", x, kernel)
```

Comment: So `kernel` is a `tf.SparseTensor`?

Comment: @jdehesa yes or a matrix with 0-1 mostly zeros (if it is better represented that way)